# How to get data attributes from a jstree element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Simple jstree list with data attributes:

```
<div id="jstree1">
    <ul>
        <li class="jstree-files jstree-open" data-file-id=716 data-size=1088>list_elemnt1<ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can successfully get the path:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#jstree1').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var path = data.instance.get_path(data.node, '/').replace('//', '/');
            });
        });
```

but I just can't find the proper way to fetch the data attributes (`data-file-id`, `data-size`)

Looked all over in both `e` and `data` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant DOM node is available in the `data` argument to the event. You can wrap it with jQuery and access the data properties conveniently:

```
$('#tree_menu').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    alert( $(data.node).data("file-id") );
});
```

or... you can just use standard DOM methods directly, which in this case is pretty much the same, as far as convenience goes.

```
$('#tree_menu').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
    alert( data.node.getAttribute("data-file-id") );
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, although I can see the relevant attributes in the console, something's not right when fetching them: https://imgur.com/eertk3H

I might be missing something extremely silly.

Comment: OK, this seems to work:

`$(data.node.data)[0].size`
`$(data.node)[0].id`

Comment: @billy That's not necessary. If you want to use the DOM properties you don't need to invoke jQuery at all. Just just use the DOM node. `data.node.data.site` and `data.node.id` will work fine.